# Get update row height in cell after heightForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, tableview

I'm trying to access the height of TableViewCell inside the setProperty of the cell.

I'm creating the cell through xib and then changing the height based on the value returned in `heightForRowAtIndexPath`

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {    
    return 200;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        RightGuideCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cellId"];
        cell.ticks = @[@"1",@"1",@"1",@"1",@"1",@"1",@"1"];
        return cell;
}
```

This is the property in my cell.

```
- (void)setTicks:(NSArray *)ticks {
    _ticks = ticks;
    CGFloat height = self.frame.size.height; //Value is 44 (size in xib)
}
```

How can I get 200 (set in `heightForRowAtIndexPath`) in the cell ?

Comment: The height is already calculated in cellForRowAtIndexPath, so you might need to reload the cell after this. That will get the new height but may be kind of ressource-heavy.

Answer (score 0):

It works in a different way.
heightForRowAtIndexPath is used by the tableview to know how much space to reserve for your cell so it can layout the cells in the desired way.
When you create a cell from a xib it has the size you draw it, is not related to the size the table view reserve for the cell.

So you must resize (change the frame) of the cell when you create it (dequeque...) or in your setTicks method if you want it to match the given space in table view, 'cause the 2 informations are not related.

Answer (score 0):

if you won't to use dynamic size of cell like this for example

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LFBTbmvFR30

The best way, try to use custom layout for collection view, for example

https://github.com/bryceredd/RFQuiltLayout

You can do amazing things with custom layout, you should to try.